# Data mining RoR-app for dribbble-shots

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, data-mining, etl

I want to data mine dribbble.com so I can make an app that registers when the best time is to upload a shot to dribbble is. I've seen someone do it for stories on news.ycombinator.com/ (Hacker News): http://hnpickup.appspot.com/.

I don't really know where to start since I'm still fairly new to RoR. I hope you can give me some pointers.

I'd like to run the app on Heroku, if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Heroku scheduler to scrape dribbble, using their own API.

Answer (score 0):

[Michael Hartl's tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning) is a good place to start for this task. The internal logic would need to change to be yours but I think that is down the road a bit. As for charting there is [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/) and [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) to name a couple of options I am familiar with.

Comment: Michael hartl's tutorial, though great, is so general. It covers a lot of stuff in RoR and how you make RoR-application, but I'm quite sure it doesn't cover datamining?!

Comment: Not in the least. It would just get you started... then you can Google ruby/rails datamining and see what comes up.

Comment: I already have a relatively good grasp on Ruby on Rails, so it's that part I'm missing. It's the part about data mining and how you could get that to function with RoR. Do you have any experience with that?